# Screen capturing with Daum PotPlayer

Tags: screen-capture

How do I capture an area or the full screen by using Daum PotPlayer?

The steps I tried:

- Open the Device Settings dialog box using either "Right Click Menu > Open > Device Settings..." or by using the <kbd>ALT+D</kbd> shortcut.
- Set the audio input device to the default PC speaker device.
- Via the "Show Capture1 Area" button in the Device Settings dialog box or by pressing the <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> shortcut, open the recording area selection rectangle.
- Close the Device Settings dialog box if it is still open and set the area you want to record by moving and resizing rectangle, or by assigning an existing window to it.

After doing these steps, I see the portion of the screen inside the rectangle on the PotPlayer window, but it doesn't record anything to my harddisk. What am I missing here? How do I start recording the screen content inside the rectangle to my hard drive in video format?

Comment: Do you mean [this?](http://howto.kouwua.net/2012/04/how-to-capture-video-screenshot-with.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it. The steps are:

- Do the steps in my question to open and adjust the recording area rectangle.
- Then go to "Right Click Menu > Video > Video Recording > Record Video..." or press <kbd>ALT+C</kbd> to open the "Video Recorder" dialog box.

[image]

- Adjust the settings in the "Video Recorder" dialog box. Some encoding profiles may fail. And when they fail, no error message is given. So, try a different encoding setting in case no file is saved.
- The video is saved in the given storage directory.

Comment: How to you customize/draw what part of the screen gets captured?

Answer (score 6):

[How to take screenshot,
snapshot, capture frames or
perform screen capture with
PotPlayer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160829081645/http://www.latestsolution.com/2016/08/how-to-take-snapshot-screenshot-with-potplayer.html)

Using Keyboard shortcut

Ctrl + E: To save current
source frame to default
Image location

Ctrl + Alt + E: To save current
screen frame to default
Image location